# Why would I need Glew to run my OpenGL application that uses glfw

Tags: linux, macos, opengl, glfw, glew

I am currently working on a simple c++ OpenGL project on both linux and macos, I have read a ton of guides on Opengl rendering for beginners and on **every single guide I have read** it's been clearly explained that I **NEED** Glew (or glad, or glut, etc.) to make sure gl functions are loaded.
*However* after correctly displaying triangles using OpenGL, I completely removed GLEW from my project and compilation and everything still worked just as fine on both Ubuntu 20.04 and MacOS high sierra,
what am I missing here?

I compile using `-lGL -lglfw` on linux and `pkg-config --libs glfw3 -framework OpenGL` on macos
My only includes are `<GLFW/glfw3.h>` and `<GLES3/gl3.h>`
My program is running `OpenGL version: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.2.6`

Am I doing something wrong?
Is glfw loading my gl functions?
Am i missing functionalities?
Is GLEW not actually needed for simple OpenGL applications?

I keep reading on running opengl without glew and all I can find are people explaining how manually loading opengl functions is possible but long, tedious, useless and borderline blasphemous, **I did not have to do that** and yet everything is working fine.
Why ?
Thank you.

Comment: If you want any OpenGL functions newer than OpenGL 2.0 (I think that was the last version where everything was exported) you need to [dynamically load them](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions). Libraries like GLEW and GLAD do this for you. GLFW is for windowing systems and user input, it is disparate from OpenGL despite the naming.

Comment: `GLES3/gl3.h` looks like a OpenGL-**es** header instead of a desktop-gl header.

Comment: @vandench OpenGL and GLSL versions both give me 4.5, what do you mean by newer than OpenGL 2.0? Would any function newer than 2.0 not work in my code? I'd love to try. thanks

Comment: @paxiuz MacOS doesn't support  OpenGL 4.5.

Comment: @BDL What does this imply? Is that header somehow different from the usual gl3.h? Does it mean I don't need GLEW since I have OpenGL ES? Does ES do the same things are glew? Which is better?

Comment: [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) is just a OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library. OpenGL (ES) is not implemented by GLEW it is implemented by the graphics driver. GLEW and GLAD just gives you access to the OpenGL (ES) API. OpenGL and OpenGL ES are different specifications, both are implemented by the graphics driver.

Comment: I was running 4.1 on macos high sierra @Rabbid76

Comment: You're using the wrong header, which declares functions which happen to be exported by the GL libraries you are using, but that is not guaranteed by any standard, and using different GL drivers might simply result in your program refusingg to start due to missing symbols. Also, using those GLES headers will limit you to GLES3 functions, but worse, there might be subtle differences in some of the functions which would not necessarily be API-compatible, calling such a function will result in weird behavior. Compiling with a header for a different library than you link is a very bad idea.